# Можно ли сказать "упорным гонениям"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Их сторонники, подвергшиеся упорным гонениям, вынуждены были искать пристанище...
Возможно ли сочетание слов "упорным гонениям"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Расширенный комментарий. Привожу по просьбе Niemand "один пяток" цитат с "упорными гонениями". (Я не буду в дальнейшем злоупотреблять "потаканиями" подобным просьбам; считаю, что научиться вводить запрос в поисковую строку Google не настолько сложная работа, чтобы перекладывать её на других.)

1.

> Несмотря на упорное гонение, направленное средневековой церковностью
>   против произведений живого народного духа... (История русской
>   литературы, Том 1, Пушкинский дом)

2.

> Этим объясняется то упорное гонение, которому они подвергались со
>   стороны христианской церкви... ("История русской музыки", учебное пособие для консерваторий, Ю.А. Келдыш)

3.

> С этих пор начинается жесточайшее и упорное гонение на Державина со
>   стороны как самого Вяземского ("Литература и действительность: вопросы теории и истории литературы", Д.Д. Благой)

4.

> Упорные гонения, позиция окрепшего правительства и неизбежное утомление, естественное для человеческой натуры, сильно охладили жар страстей. (Шарль Бодлер об искусстве, "Искусство", 1986)

5.

> Упорные гонения делают дальнейшее пребывание Пристли в Англии
>   невозможным. (Просветительское движение в Англии, Из-во МГУ, 1991).

Я привёл бы ещё не один "пяток", если бы была хоть какая-то надежда, что это поможет.

Comment: В первых четырёх примерах упомянуто, с чьей стороны были гонения, и потому словосочетание "упорные гонения" глаз не режет. В пятом же примере это очевидная калька с английского "persistent repression" :)

Answer (score 3):

УПОРНЫЙ - Проявляемый, обнаруживаемый постоянно, неизменно или с настойчивостью, упрямством. У-ое молчание. У-ое нежелание. У-ое постоянство. У-ое противостояние. Преследует у-ая мысль о чём-л. // Длительное время не прекращающийся, не ослабевающий. У-ые слухи. Долгая и у-ая зима.

Упорные гонения - такие, которые проявляются длительно время, без прекращения, настойчиво.

Comment: Мне казалось, что УПОРНЫЙ относится больше к состоянию, чем к действию. А ГОНЕНИЕ больше действие, чем состояние. Или не так?

Comment: Нет, не обязательно.

Answer (score 1):

Мне думается, что в этой ситуации важен контекст.

Если в тексте присутствует упоминание о гонителе, то словосочетание "упорные гонения" легитимно, ибо оно подразумевает, что означенное качество (упорство) относится к упомянутому гонителю. Происходит перенос качества с действия на носителя.

Если же о носителе этого качества в тексте не сказано, то я бы заменил "упорным" на "непрекращающимся" или "непрестанным".

Comment: Носитель в таких случаях обычно подразумевается вполне конкретный, даже если он не указан явно. Это просто комментарий, не возражение — я не уверен, что могу возразить.